# Proxy server with output bound to individual network interface

Tags: proxy, windows-10

I have a server running Windows 10, and I want to host a proxy server on it which directs outbound traffic to an individual network interface.

I have looked around and have not been able to find a straightforward solution to this.

I have attempted to use Squid. Other serverfault threads such as [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/565165/squid-specify-outgoing-network-interface) suggest the use of `tcp_outgoing_address`, but this doesn't work for IP addresses which may change.

Is there a better way to create a HTTP/SOCKS Proxy server, of which the output can be easily bound to a specific network interface?

Comment: your question is to broad, software recommendations are off topic. please be more specific what you want to route where.

Comment: @djdomi Simply a HTTP/SOCKS5/SOCKS4 proxy server which is able to route output data through a specific network interface, rather than a specific IP.

Comment: squid is able to do that mostly, but as already stated, your question is too unclear

Comment: @djdomi Could you please specify where specifically you would like more details?